# WPF User Control with Dependency Property not working

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties

I am writing a WPF application and have a User Control with a couple datagrids that I want to use in multiple places. In each place, I want the font size to be different.

Here's what I'm trying:

.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="RoviPutt.Controls.Leaderboard"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="605" d:DesignWidth="890">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGrid}">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding TextSize}"/>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ma:FlipView IsBannerEnabled="False">
            <ma:FlipView.Items>
                <Grid>
                    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ShowOverall.Leaders}" Margin="50" BorderThickness="2">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="RANK" Binding="{Binding Rank}" Width="Auto"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="NAME" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="*"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="COMPANY" Binding="{Binding Company}" Width="*"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="SCORE" Binding="{Binding Score, StringFormat=N2}" Width="Auto"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </Grid>
                <Grid>
                    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SessionOverall.Leaders}" Margin="50" BorderThickness="2">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="RANK" Binding="{Binding Rank}" Width="Auto"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="NAME" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="*"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="COMPANY" Binding="{Binding Company}" Width="*"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="SCORE" Binding="{Binding Score, StringFormat=N2}" Width="Auto"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </Grid>
            </ma:FlipView.Items>
        </ma:FlipView>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class Leaderboard : UserControl
{
    public Leaderboard()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var vm = new LeaderboardViewModel();
        vm.TextSize = TextSize;
        DataContext = vm;
    }

    #region Dependency Properties

    public int TextSize
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(TextSizeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextSizeProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextSizeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TextSize", typeof(int),
          typeof(Leaderboard));

    #endregion
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class LeaderboardViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public LeaderboardViewModel()
    {

    }

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Font size
    /// </summary>
    private int textSize;
    public int TextSize
    {
        get { return textSize; }
        set { SetProperty(ref textSize, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Show overall game score leaderboard
    /// </summary>
    private Leaderboard showOverall;
    public Leaderboard ShowOverall
    {
        get { return showOverall; }
        set { SetProperty(ref showOverall, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Session overall game score leaderboard
    /// </summary>
    private Leaderboard sessionOverall;
    public Leaderboard SessionOverall
    {
        get { return sessionOverall; }
        set { SetProperty(ref sessionOverall, value); }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Everytime I set the TestSize attribute using

```
<Leaderboard TextSize="20"/>
```

and check the .xaml.cs, I'm getting a TextSize of 0. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the binding is trying to find the `TextSize` property in the `DataContext` which is the viewmodel, not in the `UserControl`'s own properties.

Try giving a name to your `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl .... x:Name="leaderBoard">
```

And change the binding to the following:

```
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding TextSize, ElementName=leaderBoard}"/>
```

When you have a problem with a binding, always check Visual Studio's Output pane. Binding errors should be listed there and will give you a hint of what might be wrong.